# Managing UI requirements in a microservice architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices

We have different client applications (each is built with a different UI and is targeted to a different sales channels) that are used to capture orders that ultimately need to be processed by our factory.

At first we decided to offer a single "order" microservice that would be used by all these client applications for business rules execution and data storage. This microservice will also trigger our backoffice processes such as client profile update, order analysis, documents storage to our electronic vault, invoicing, communications, etc.

The challenge we are facing is that these client applications are developed by teams that are external to ours (we are a backoffice team only). Each team responsible to develop a client application will be able to offer a different UX to their users (some will allow to save orders in an incomplete state, some wil allow to capture data using a specific worflow, some will use text fields instead of listboxes for some values, etc.).

This diversity of behaviors from client applications is an issue because our microservice logic will become very complex to be able to support all those UI requirements. Moreover, everytime a change will be made to one of the client applications, we will have to modify our microservice which is a case of strong coupling.

My questions are: What would be your best advice to manage this issue? Should we let each application capture the data the way it wants (and persist it if needed in its own database) and let them call our microservice only when an order is complete and compliant to our API contract?

Should we keep our idea of having a single "order" microservice for everyone and force each client application to capture the data the same way?

Any other option?

We want to reduce the duplication of data and business rules in our ecosystem but in the same time we don't want our 'order' microservice to become a mess.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to format your question, highlight the important aspects, create items and sub-items whether necessary, create paragraphs, break lines. This will make your text more clear to read and encourage people to answer.

Comment: Looks you have **Differents order workflows** and you want to keep the state of incomplete orders until you have all the information.  Does the order form each UI type has the same data ? Are concern of each your UI making diffent requests for you service ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @EduCosta. Sorry for the bad editing. I posted my question in a hurry and did not take care of the formatting. Hopefully the new version is clearer. It also gives details that are related to your questions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover, everytime a change will be made to one of the client applications, we will have to modify our microservice which is a case of strong coupling.

This rings alarm bells for me. A change to a UI shouldn't require a change to a backend service. (The exception would be if a new feature were being added to a system and the backend service needed to play a part in supporting that feature, but I wouldn't just call that a change to a client.) As you have said, it's strong coupling, and that's something to be avoided in a microservices environment.

Ideally, your service should provide a generic, programmatic API that is flexible enough to support multiple UIs (or other non-UI applications) without having any knowledge of how the UIs work.

It sounds like you have some decisions to make about what responsibilities your service will and won't take on:

- Does it make more sense for your generic orders service to facilitate the storage/retrieval/completion of incomplete orders, or to force its clients to manage this somewhere else?
- Does it make more sense for your generic service to provide facilities to assist in the tracking of workflows, or to force the UIs that need that functionality to find it elsewhere?
- For clients that want to show list boxes, does it make sense for your generic orders service to provide APIs that aid in populating those boxes?

> Should we let each application capture the data the way it wants (and persist it if needed in its own database) and let them call our microservice only when an order is complete and compliant to our API contract?

It really depends on whether you think that's the most sensible way for your service to behave. Something that will play into that will be how similar or dissimilar the needs of each UI is. If 4 out of 5 UIs have the same needs, it could well make sense to support that generically in your service. If every single UI behaves differently to the others, putting that functionality in your generic orders service would amount to storing frontend code somewhere that it doesn't belong.

It seems like there might also be some organisational considerations to these decisions. If the teams using your service are *only* frontend teams (i.e. without capacity/skills to build backend services), then someone will still have to build the backend functionality they require.

> Should we keep our idea of having a single "order" microservice for everyone and force each client application to capture the data the same way?

Yes to the idea of having a single order service with a generic interface for everyone. With regards to forcing client applications to capture data a certain way, your API will only dictate what they need to do to create an order. You can't (and shouldn't) force anything on them about the way they capture the data before calling your service. They can do it however they like. The questions are really around whether your service supports various models of capture or pushes that responsibility back to the frontend.

> What would be your best advice to manage this issue?

Collaborate with the teams that will use the service. Gather as much information as you can about the use cases in which they intend to use it. Discover what is common for the majority and choose what of that you will support. Create a semi-formal spec (e.g. well-documented [Open API](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/README.md)), share it with the client teams, ask for feedback, and iterate. For the parts of the UIs that aren't common across clients, strongly consider telling those teams they'll need to support those elements of their design themselves, especially if they represent significant work on your end.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice @Graham Lea. Your insights are very useful.